# Need a 500-line AI summary of a text file

Tags: gratis, artificial-intelligence

I have an 8000-line, 907 KB text file converted from a PDF book and need a 500-line summary using AI tools. Online options have character limits; looking for GitHub libraries or alternative online tools.